# Why doesn't my internal mic work?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have no sound in the Yahoo chat room.

I have a new HP Pavilion windows 7

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying you have no sound coming out your speakers, or you cannot transmit sound using your microphone?

Make sure the drivers are installed properly by checking under device manager that it is recognised as a microphone. Right click "Computer" on your desktop and select properties, then in the left hand column of the following window, select "Device Manager". Find the microphone in the list and make sure it doesn't have an exclamation mark next to it. If it is not recognised, you will need to find the driver from HP for the microphone.

If this fails to work, go to the sound preferences by Right clicking on the volume icon in the task bar ( near the clock) and select "Recording Devices" then make sure the correct device is set as default.

Finally, make sure it is not muted ;)